# Query selects the wrong boolean value

Tags: java, sql, servlets

I get unpredictable results out of my table with 3 boolean columns.

```
public ArrayList<Benutzerdaten> gibAlleBenutzer() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Benutzerdaten";
        Benutzerdaten b;
        ArrayList<Benutzerdaten> benutzer = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                b = new Benutzerdaten(rs.getString("LoginName"), rs.getString("Name")
                        , rs.getString("Vorname"), rs.getString("Email"), rs.getInt("Passwort")
                        , rs.getBoolean("P"), rs.getBoolean("B"), rs.getBoolean("A"));
                benutzer.add(b);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return benutzer;
    }
```

As you can see I have the 3 boolean columns called P, B and A. One of the entries from the table 'Benutzerdaten' has  P=false, B=false and A=true

However, I get a different result from this query:  P=false, B=true and A=false which I checked with a debugger. I can't think of any reason why the query returns this wrong result. Why does this happen?

The constructor of my Benutzerdaten class:

```
public Benutzerdaten(String Login, String Name, String Vorname, String Email, int Passwort
, boolean produktkatalog, boolean benutzerverwaltung, boolean auswertung) {
    this.Login = Login;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Vorname = Vorname;
    this.Email = Email;
    this.Passwort = Passwort;
    this.produktkatalog = produktkatalog;
    this.benutzerverwaltung = benutzerverwaltung;
    this.auswertung = auswertung;
}
```

The expected values of the boolean columns by entry:
0 = false, 1 = true

P  B  A

a. 0  0  1

b. 1  1  0

c. 1  0  0

But what I got:

a. 1  1  1

b. 1  0  1

c. 1  0  0

Comment: Have you checked your table to see if the results match what is in the actual database?

Comment: Yes. When I update the table, it is completly fine. Inserting something is no problem. But when I have a query to get something out of the DB, I get this weird results

Comment: And what exactly you checked with debugger, ResultSet or entity? Also could you please show constructor params for Benutzerdaten class

Comment: It would help for you to list your expected output as well as your actual output. From what you have listed though, it isn't exactly clear what you are asking.

Comment: @edmarisov I checked the entity.

Comment: Overall looks ok. One thing can be checked - if there is no spaces/tabs etc characters in P, B, A columns - because if there is not 1, "1", "true", true - behavior is undefined.

Comment: Have you tried naming the columns in your request, and using positional getBooleans?